# "/" in filename, not as a directory separator

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, filenames, macos

My problem is that if the user enters a filename with a "/" in it, it will be saved to another directory. Is there a way to prevent this, so I could have "/" in the filename?

For example, the file named "page 8/9.txt"should not be saved in the directory "page 8" as "9.txt."

**Edit:**
The `:` worked fine for me! thanks [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r)

Comment: Mac OS X or iOS ? Please tag appropriately. Either way a `/` in a filename should get converted to a `:` unless you're bypassing the normal UI stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X normally translates `/` to `:` and *vice versa* transparently, so long as you do not bypass the usual APIs for file system navigation and file I/O.

Answer (score 4):

No, "most" file systems (I can't think of any counter-examples, though I assume some do exist) disallow the / character, even those that don't use it as a directory separator (e.g. FAT and NTFS).

You're going to have to sanitise your input, but that's a good general habit to get into anyway!

Comment: Windows accepts `/` as a directory separator as well as `\ `.

Comment: Ah cheers, wasn't aware, and don't have a Windows machine handy here to test on; all I remembered was that it wasn't a legal char in a name. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but as you noticed i am using objective-c, which is for mac / iPhone

Comment: I have Objective-C code writing to FAT; regardless, the FAT/NTFS mention was merely an additional example of "things that won't accept /"